# Как передвигать окно не имея краев?

Tags: c#, winforms, form

При работе с winforms, возникла такая проблема:
Надо передвигать окно с помощью мыши, у которого нет границ (`FormBorderStyle = None`)
Как делать так чтобы можно было передвигать держав отмеченное место на картине.
Серый  это `menuStrip`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592876/make-a-borderless-form-movable) вроде то, что вам нужно, но а вообще, хотите хороший дизайн - переходите на `WPF`, там это делается написанием всего 1 слова, `DragMove();`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool IsDown;
    Point PrevMousePosition;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        IsDown = true;
        PrevMousePosition = MousePosition;
    }

    private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        IsDown = false;
    }

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(IsDown)
        {
            Point CurrentMousePosition = MousePosition;
            this.Location = new Point(this.Location.X+(CurrentMousePosition.X-PrevMousePosition.X), this.Location.Y + (CurrentMousePosition.Y - PrevMousePosition.Y));
            PrevMousePosition = CurrentMousePosition;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну, я добавил это все в код.  Но я не понял, как прикрепит это к menuStrip?

Comment: Вам нужно немного модифицировать код, в моем решении сделана подписка на события самой формы, Вам соответственно нужно сделать подписку на события MenuStrip.